# Localized name for NSCalendar

Tags: swift, nscalendar

I’d like to create a table view with available calendars.

```
…
var cells: [CLProperty.PropertyCell] = []
let calendars = [NSCalendarIdentifierBuddhist, NSCalendarIdentifierChinese, NSCalendarIdentifierEthiopicAmeteAlem, NSCalendarIdentifierEthiopicAmeteMihret, NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian, NSCalendarIdentifierHebrew, NSCalendarIdentifierIndian, NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic, NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil, NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicTabular, NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicUmmAlQura, NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601, NSCalendarIdentifierJapanese, NSCalendarIdentifierPersian, NSCalendarIdentifierRepublicOfChina]
for cal in calendars {
  let co = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: cal)
  let ll: String = … // method to obtain the localized calendar name
  cells.append(CLProperty.PropertyCell(cellIdentifier: CLProperty.PropertyCellTypes.SimpleCell, propertyID: NSCalendar.Properties.Calendar, cellBehavior: .None, caption: ll, currentValue: co))
}
…
```

I haven’t been able to find an appropriate method for that. Should I use rather `NSLocalizedString` for that?